# How to create a simple event consisting of Event Id and a mathematic operation?

Tags: python, events, timer, pygame

I've been slowly trying to learn pygame and python and I've tried to make a simple spritesheet animation. I'm fairly sure I'm not doing it right, but I'm still trying to learn how classes really work and so forth. So far I have a key press returning `True` and a release returning `False`. `True` then activates the cycle of the animation.

```
while done == False:
for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_speed = walk_speed
            dir = 1
            cycle = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            x_speed = 0 - walk_speed
            dir = 0
            cycle = True

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_speed = 0
            dir = 1
            cycle = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            x_speed = 0
            dir = 0
            cycle = False


    if cycle == True:
        it += 1
        if it > 6:
            it = 0
        pygame.time.set_timer(it, 100)

    elif cycle == False:
        it = 1
        pygame.time.set_timer(it, 0)
        it = 1


    ennis.speed = x_speed
if it > 6:
    it = 0
if dir == 1:
    ennis.sprite = walking_right[it]
if dir == 0:
    ennis.sprite = walking_left[it]
ennis.update()
```

I know this may be a horrible, messy, rudimentary way to do it, but it works and I understand it! Well, it almost works.

At the moment, the Event Id passed into `pygame.time.set_timer()` is the `it` variable, which throws up a `Value Error`, saying the Id must be between `NOEVENT(0) and NUMEVENTS(32)`. So, the way I see it, is that I need to make an event that increments `it` by 1, and resets to 0 when it gets above 6.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: a small tip - `if something == True` is redundant, you can just write `if something` and `if not something` for a false statement

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use events for animation, one such use could use could be blinking stars.

How pygame event queue works:

The operating system sends your keyboard and mouse presses to the queue.  When you call `pygame.event.get()` it gets the first event from the queue. After that you can check for its type : KEYDOWN, and the corresponding button.

What set_timer does, it sets a repeating event of your choice. If we set the timer to 1 second, with the event id of 12, we will get an event every second. We could then do some action, for example play a sound. It's not really used in animations.

How an animated sprite is written:

Instead of your boolean values, you should have states: `STANDING` and `WALKING`.
A sprite should have an update method, where you move the sprite, and change its surface.
Every call to update should assign the next surface. To have some sort of delay you can use the Clock, that will return the amount of ms since the last call.
That way, you can accumulate the result of Clock until some top value, when you will change the sprite.